# Connection Refused RealVNC and Same with Remote Desktop Program Windows Server 2012

Tags: networking, windows-server-2012-r2, rdp, vnc

So i set up a virtual machine on QEMU on my linux machine hoping to get some windows server running but when i tried to set up RDP i couldn't connect through my client. So i thought i'd try RealVNC instead of RDP and when i tried to connect it just hung and said timed out... So then i went to RealVNCs test page and it said Connection Refused (111). I can connect to the internet just fine, i tried turning my firewall off and nothing has worked.. I'm not sure if it's a connection issue or what.

Really Stumped here.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you checked Windows Firewall on the Windows machine?  Got to poke holes in it, or disable it.

Comment: Yeah, i disabled it. still not worki